# Automatically push after `git rebase --update-refs`

Tags: git

Git 2.38 introduced the `--update-refs` flag to the rebase command. If you have a chain of branches, it will update all the branches in the chain. I've found this incredibly useful when breaking a large PR down into more easily reviewed PRs.

However, after `git rebase --update-refs dev`, I need to push all the refs to GitHub to update the PRs. This requires a set of `git checkout branch1 && git push --force-with-lease && git checkout branch2  && git push --force-with-lease && ...`.

Is there a way built into git to handle this automatically? I basically want to `push --force-with-lease` automatically for any branches updated during a `rebase --update-refs`.

Comment: Thanks @TTT! If you put that response as an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure that you can do this "automatically", but you can get pretty close.

When you use the `--update-refs` option with `rebase`, the output will tell you all of your local branches that were updated:

```
$ git rebase origin/main my-branch --update-refs

Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/my-branch.
Updated the following refs with --update-refs:
        refs/heads/some-branch-1
        refs/heads/some-branch-2
```

From there you can use that output to build a single command to force push all of your modified branches:

```
git push --force-with-lease origin my-branch some-branch-1 some-branch-2
```

**Tip:** when using the `--update-refs` option and there is at least one branch to update, you'll notice that the number of actions in the output is higher than the number of commits you are rebasing. This is because every instruction line is counted (including blank lines). You can add the `-i` option (for interactive rebase) to see exactly what instructions are used. This is also a good way to see what branches *will* be updated when you run the command, if you wish to know that beforehand.

Answer (score 3):

To save from copy/pasting, if you have a branch naming convention, such as `fix/a-bug` or `project/beta`, it's possible to target all branches branched from a target using `git branch --contains`:

```
git branch --list 'project/beta*' --format='%(refname:lstrip=2)' | xargs -I "{}" git push origin {}
```

*The branch pattern (in the example above `project/beta*`) is optional.*

Comment: --contains refers to a commit, not to a pattern

Comment: Actually to make filter on the branch name one must pas the filter string after `--list`.

Answer (score 1):

After trying @MattyRad solution without success I got to polish it to the following working solution:

```
git branch --list "*jony*" | xargs -I "{}" git push origin {} --force-with-lease
```

This will force push (with lease) all your local branches. If you are using a naming convention, you can place it on the list pattern.

Answer (score -1):

You can push all matching branches at once.

```
git push origin :
```

> The special refspec : (or +: to allow non-fast-forward updates)
> directs Git to push "matching" branches: for every branch that exists
> on the local side, the remote side is updated if a branch of the same
> name already exists on the remote side. [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#_options).

Comment: In the context of this question you would need to use force push. If you are force pushing every branch you have locally, then please use this command with extreme caution!

Comment: @TTT that's true, but the OP is specifically mentioning `--force-with-lease`, which prevent part of the bad thing. Still, even with the _lease_ it's possible to unintentionally push wrong changes, make sure shared branches are protected.

Comment: @bric3 even with `--force-with-lease`, you still might force push lots of branches that you didn't mean to push. For example, suppose you have 50 old local branches, and you rebase 5 of them like in this question. You run this command and those 5 can't be pushed because they need to be force pushed. So then you run this command with `--force-with-lease` and it does what you want for those 5 branches, but also blows away the other 45 branches on the remote and replaces them with your super old versions.

Comment: Indeed I end to have a good branch hygiene but it's easy to have an old branch hanging around and depending on the topology of the repo this could get really bad as you mentioned.